# Deleted product before disabling

Tags: products-management, ce-1.4.1.1

I am new to Magento and I accidentally deleted a product prior to disabling the product on a store.  While you are not able to purchase the product as when you select the product from the products listings it says product is unavailable.  But the product is showing on the product listings page and I need to remove that but am uncertain how as I cannot find the product and then disable it for that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-index the catalog.

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/102-customizing-magento/how-to-reindex-your-magento-website

Or in command line

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindexall
```

Comment: how do i reindex the catalog